# How do I set up payments on my PayPal business account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

Can anyone help me set up payments for my PayPal business account?
I need to set up recurring payments (subscription) once a month, set up standard payments, set up payment for services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow is not the place to ask for support with setting up a PayPal account. But you can create buttons at https://www.paypal.com/buttons

If you add more than one smart button to a web page, ensure the SDK is only loaded *one* time per page (before any of the buttons are rendered) and that each button then renders to a `<div>` with a unique HTML `id`.

Comment: I want to hire a developer to solve this problem. Can I do it here?

Comment: No, you're probably looking for a freelancer. StackOverflow's Job section is for full time work

Comment: Could you recommend me where I can go for help? Where can I find a freelancer?